# Android Device Manager password reset doesn't work

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, password, android-device-manager

I accidentally forgot the password for my Galaxy S3 Neo (i9301i). People suggested I make a new one by locking it from Android Device Manager. However, when I send a new password to my device, the Samsung logo appears, similar to booting but faster. After that when I try to use the new password it rejects it. How should I proceed (I'm not rooted btw)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have forgotten your password then the phone should display a forgot password option if you enter the wrong password. Look closely. It will let you reset it with your email.